# Azure Mobile Service changes are not being committed?

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-mobile-services

Peculiar problem arised just today. My Azure Mobile Service has been working fine until now, but now that I make updates to the script, it doesn't seem to update in to the production version of the service.

I have tried pulling and pushing through git as well and I get the right scripts but the functionality when I use the service doesn't match my changes (I added some really distinctive log data to see if the changes were going through and they were not). It has been almost 2 hours now and it still doesn't work. I also tried adding tables, removing tables, and editing scripts. Nothing seems to trigger a deploy.

While this sounds like a service issue, does anyone know how I could debug this further?

Comment: Can you provide the name of your service?

Comment: This issue resolved itself after a few hours. I'm curious to know what could cause such delay though. Name is 'squabble'.